# How to extend ActiveSupport::Concern correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is the different between the 2 concerns below? In what cases should I use `base`?

Option 1

```
module SetSomething
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_action :set_something
  end
end
```

Option 2

```
module SetSomething
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do |base|
    if base < ActionController::Base
      before_action :set_something
    end
  end
end
```